# In Node.js, How can I turn a module's function into a sinon stub?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I have a Node.js project with two `.js` files. My `package.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "some-module-name-here",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "sinon": "^17.0.0"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

`node --version` outputs `v20.8.0`

In `module.js`, I have:

```js
export function foo() {
    return bar();
}

function bar() {
    return 12;
}
```

In `test.js`, I have:

```js
import * as sinon from "sinon";

import * as module from "./module.js";

sinon.stub(module, "bar");
```

I want to turn `module.bar` into a sinon stub, so that `foo()` will always call the stub instead of the real `bar()`. That way I can test *only* the behavior of `foo`, while ignoring the details of `bar`'s behavior, which will simplify my test code greatly. But unfortunately, I can't. When I try to run this code, (using `node ./test.js`) I get:

```
[snip]/sinon-esm.js:3849
        throw new TypeError("ES Modules cannot be stubbed");
              ^
```

How can I replace `module.bar` with a sinon stub?

With the code above, I would expect for the `sinon.stub` function to replace `module.bar` with a sinon stub. Another thing I've tried is:

```js
module.bar = sinon.stub();
```

But this just gives me the error:

```
[snip]/test.js:6
module.bar = sinon.stub();
           ^

TypeError: Cannot add property bar, object is not extensible
```